# Proper way to pass multiple values with protocols in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

So I have two ViewControllers. First (MapVC) with map and second (SettingsVC) with many settings that need to be applied to this map.

I thought it would be nice idea to create protocol like

```
protocol MapSettingsDelegate: class {}
```

I know that I can specify function inside this protocol. But how I should do it when I have many settings - how should I pass them from SettingsVC to MapVC.

Comment: Define a struct? `MapSettings`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example:

```
struct MySettings {
    var value1: String
    var value2: String
    // and so on...
}

protocol MapSettingsDelegate: class {
    func settingsUpdated(newSettings: MySettings)
}
```

and implement it inside your controller

```
class MapVC : MapSettingsDelegate {
    ...
    func settingsUpdated(newSettings: MySettings) {
        // Update everything you need
    }
    ...
}
```

Feel free to ask for details